# How to add suffix in a line using regex?

Tags: regex

How to add suffix in a line using regex? This is my regex: 
https://regex101.com/r/vV4zX8/1

The result should be like this:

My sample input is:

```
one

two


three

four


five

six


seven
```

So far all I've been able to come up with to use is:

`\n` replace with `- digit \n`

But I need the output of:

```
one - digit

two - digit


three - digit

four - digit


five - digit

six - digit


seven - digit
```

Comment: use `\n+` instead of `\n`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried already but all newlines removed

Comment: What language/regex engine are you using? Nuances in matching behavior play a role here.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the regex `\b$` which ensures there's a match where a 'word' ends, and replace with  `- digit` (or `\b(\n|$)` with a replacement of  `- digit$1` if you don't want to use multiline)

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ1gX6/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `([^\r?\n])$`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:**

```
(.+)$
```

or

```
(.)$
```

And don't forget to enable mulitine modifier `m`.

**Replacement string:**

```
\1 - digit
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vV4zX8/2)

Comment: Eh, hold on. If a multi-line string is matched, `\n\n` will be matched by `.$`. Whether this has a chance of working depends on the regex engine used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this : check below image
[image: Check This]

For [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vV4zX8/3)

Comment: did you check his expected output?

Comment: The empty lines (where more than one of them appeared in sequence) still look removed to me. OP stated in the comments that that was a problem.